# Pandas drop_duplicates Issue

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to remove duplicate entries by specifying a particular column.
The column is labelled 'sent_name'

```
print(new_df)

                                  sent_name  \
0            Abbey Road Station, London, UK   
1            Abbey Wood Station, London, UK   
2                 Acton Station, London, UK   
3         Acton Central Station, London, UK 


                                                Name        Lat       Lng  \
0                            Abbey Road, London E15, UK  51.531930  0.003760   
1                            Abbey Wood, London SE2, UK  51.491060  0.121420   
2     Station Parade, West Acton London Underground ...  51.518055 -0.281053   
3                          Acton Central, London W3, UK  51.508720 -0.262950   

                                                   type  
0     [u'transit_station', u'point_of_interest', u'e...  
1     [u'transit_station', u'point_of_interest', u'e...  
2     [u'train_station', u'transit_station', u'point...  
3     [u'transit_station', u'point_of_interest', u'e...
```

I have tried

```
new_df.drop_duplicates(["sent_name"])
```

and

```
   new_df.drop_duplicates(subset="sent_name")
```

On inspection, nither of these removes all of the duplicates.

For example,

```
1038           Woodford Station, London, UK   
1040           Woodford Station, London, UK   
1041           Woodford Station, London, UK   
1043           Woodford Station, London, UK   
1044           Woodford Station, London, UK
1038  South Woodford London Underground Station, Geo...  51.591789  0.027315   
1040  Woodford, Woodford, Woodford Green, Greater Lo...  51.606900  0.034000   
1041                     South Woodford, London E18, UK  51.591910  0.027360   
1043            South Woodford (Stop C), London E18, UK  51.591312  0.029013   
1044            South Woodford (Stop D), London E18, UK  51.592010  0.027658  
1038  [u'train_station', u'transit_station', u'point...  
1040  [u'transit_station', u'point_of_interest', u'e...  
1041  [u'transit_station', u'point_of_interest', u'e...  
1043  [u'transit_station', u'point_of_interest', u'e...  
1044  [u'transit_station', u'point_of_interest', u'e...
```

Comment: Are you assigning the result back? `new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates(["sent_name"])` by default a copy of the modified df is returned unless you pass param `inplace=True`, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) as by default `inplace=False` and nearly all pandas ops return a copy.

So either:

```
new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates(["sent_name"])
```

or

```
new_df.drop_duplicates(["sent_name"], inplace=True)
```

will work